# How do i update mongodb data using id in node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to update the data from client side in mongodb but I can see clicked updated Id value in node js but it does not update in mongodb wat to do..    help me to update the values in mongo db using id values

```
router.post('/datapassfup', (req, res) => {
        console.log("updated values are",req.body)
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db("mohan");
            var myquery = { id: req.body.id };
            var newvalues = { $set: {name: req.body.name, username: 
            req.body.username } };
            dbo.collection("customers").updateMany(myquery,newvalues, 
            function(err, res) {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log("1 document updated");
              db.close();
            });
          });
        });
```

Comment: in the consle window i can see the updated values in node js

Comment: i think `{ id: req.body.id };` should be `{_id: req.body.id };`

Comment: `db.collection.deleteOne({_id: req.body.id})`

Comment: sorry for my mistake. I need updation code

Comment: Can you give a bit of context on the update operation: what does a document from `customers` collection look like, can the `id` field map to may documents or it's unique? If the latter is true then `updateMany` is not appropriate for that case.

Answer (score 1):

if you use the mongodb id for you query then you need to create a new objectid for _id search

```js
const {ObjectId} = require("mongodb");


const query = {_id:new ObjectId(req.body.id)}
```